# Tin/bismuth/lead solder alloy is not sticking to copper

Tags: soldering

I purchased a custom solder satisfying my melting point requirement, but I'm having a hard time soldering my parts together.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Have you got the metal hot enough? Have you used enough of the right type of flux?

Comment: This is not a 'Dear Diary' site. You need to ask a question.

Comment: Set the temperature of iron lower, like  200° C.

Answer (score 5):

Clean the copper and add more flux.

Answer (score 0):

Try soldering under Argon gas.  Bismuth-oxide is nasty stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Bismuth/tin/lead 50/25/25 called Rose metal. Melting point under 100°C. That stuff used mostly for safely removing elements from PCB. Usual soldering iron temperature 300°C may be too high. Regular flux, as rosin, may not work good at low temperature.